# Proving convergence in different metric spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

> Q:Consider the metric space $(R, d)$ where $d$ is the distance defined by $d(x, y) = min\{1,|x−y|\}$,∀x, y∈R. Let $(x_n)_1^\infty$ be a sequence in R, and l∈R. Show that if the sequence $(x_n)_1^\infty$ converges to $l \in(R, d)$, then $(x_n)_1^\infty $converges to l in R with the Euclidean/usual distance.

The question is above now and then my thoughts are we can just use the defintion:

$(x_n) \rightarrow x$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $$d(x_n,x) < \epsilon \ when \ n \geq N$$

if we do this for the first case with specified space we get:

$d(x_n) = min \{1,|x_n - x| \} < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Once I have this I'm a bit stuck on how to progress further maybe I could use the fact the minimum would always be $>0$. Since distance are by definition larger than $0$ and then somehow relate it to the fact

$|x_n - x| < \epsilon \ whenever \ n\geq N$

But overall, I'm stuck and I would appreciate some guidance on this thank you!

Comment: If $\epsilon < 1$ then $\min\{1,|x_n-x|\} < \epsilon$ implies $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I just realised it said Euc. distance so sqrt(x_n^2 - l^2) < epsilon, is there any hints for this ?

Comment: The Euclidean distance on the line is $|x_n - l| = \sqrt{|x_n-l|^2}$, not $\sqrt{x_n^2 - l^2}$.

Comment: On this site people prefer $\Bbb R\;\Bbb Z\;\Bbb N\;\Bbb Q$ for the reals, integers, natural numbers, and rationals.... LaTex is  \Bbb R, \Bbb Z, \Bbb N,\Bbb Q.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ convergesto $l$ with respect to $d$ OR converges to $l$ with respect to the usual metric then there exists $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\forall m,n >n_0\,(|x_n-x_m|<1 \;\land\; |x_n-l|<1).$$